# An exercise from Knuth's book - Proving a formula by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I would like to find a formula for this sum:

$$
    \frac{1^3}{1^4+4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4+4} + \frac{5^3}{5^4+4} - ... + \frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}
$$

The answer given (Knuth's book, The Art of Computer Programming Volume 1, Third Edition, Section 1.2.1, Exercise 11) is $$ \frac{(-1^n)(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}$$
Please give me an approach or a solution to get this sum.

I tried to solve by pairing the consecutive terms. The last and the second last terms will correspond to $(2n+1)$ and $(2n-1)$ respectively. But this approach couldn't yield much.

The second part is to prove this sum by induction, i.e we've to prove this equation:
$$
    \frac{1^3}{1^4+4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4+4} + \frac{5^3}{5^4+4} - ... + \frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4} = \frac{(-1^n)(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}
$$

I approached it like this:

The sum is correct for $k=1$( and $k=0$). (k is a non-negative integer)

Assuming that the sum is correct for $k = 0,1,..,n$
we'll prove that its correct for $k=n+1$.

The sum for $k=n+1$ will be equal to: `the sum for k=n` + `the last term`, i.e. $$ \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2(n+1)+1)^3}{(2(n+1)+1)^4+4}$$

This should then be proved equal to $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}((n+1)+1)}{4((n+1)+1)^2+1}$$
which again I'm not able to do. So, please help in proving this also.

P.S.: Someone please create a 'knuth' or 'taocp' tag for mathematical questions of this book.

Comment: Your second approach does work, you have to simplify the difference, and you'll find $0$. Regarding the knuth tag, notice he's an author, not a mathematical field by himself. It would not be wise to create a tag for each good math textbook.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, yes the second approach worked. Regarding the tags you are right that they shouldn't be made for an author or a book. But Stackoverflow has these tags for the programming related questions of this book so I thought maybe we could have these here also.

Comment: I agree entirely with @Jean-ClaudeArbaut as far as creating tags for textbooks. But... This is after all the Knuth. You could create a tag (As they did in Stackoverflow) but that is due to the importance of the work. Not every textbook would get this kind of treatment, even on Stackoverflow

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Yes, TAoCP is an excellent work and I am sure many people have followed it. So, a tag would be helpful for people finding questions about this. 
Since, creating tag requires 1000 reputation, I'm not able to create it

Comment: Post on meta.stackexchange, it's best to gauge the opinion of the community. If there isn't very clear opposition, I would be willing to create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have$$ \begin{align} (2n+1)^4+4&= A^4+B^2\\\\ &=(A^4+2A^2B+B^2)-2A^2B\\\\
   &=(A^2+B)^2-2A^2B\\\\
   &=\left((2n+1)^2+2\right)^2-4\left(2n+1\right)^2\\\\
   &=\left((2n+1)^2+2-2(2n+1)\right)\left((2n+1)^2+2+2(2n+1)\right)\\\\
   &=\left(4n^2+1\right)\left(4(n+1)^2+1\right) \end{align}$$

Second you have$$ \begin{align} \frac{n}{4n^2+1}+\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}&= \frac{n\left(4(n+1)^2+1\right)+(n+1)\left(4n^2+1\right)}{\left(4n^2+1\right)\left(4(n+1)^2+1\right)}\\\\ &=\frac{8n^3+12n^2+6n+1}{(2n+1)^4+4}\\\\
  &=\frac{(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}\\\\
  \end{align} $$
Now, setting $\displaystyle u_n:=\frac{(-1)^n n}{4n^2+1}$, you see from the preceding lines that $$\begin{align} u_n- u_{n+1}&=\frac{(-1)^n n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}\\\\&=(-1)^n \left(\frac{n}{4n^2+1}+\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}\end{align} $$
and by telescoping, you obtain what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I've understood how this is being used to prove the sum by induction. But for the first part where we have to find the expression for the sum, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

Take two consecutive sums and subtract them (actually you will be adding as the signs alternate):

$$\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}+\frac{n+2}{4(n+2)^2+1}=\frac{8n^3+36n^2+54n+27}{16n^4+96n^3+216n^2+216n+85}.$$

The numerator is $(2n+3)^3$, and the denominator is $(2n+3)^4+4$.

---

To make this derivation more symmetric and manageable, you can use a half-integer index, $m=n+3/2$:

$$\frac{2m-1}{(2m-1)^2+1}+\frac{2m+1}{(2m+1)^2+1}=
\frac{2m-1}{(4m^2+2)-4m}+\frac{2m+1}{(4m^2+2)+4m}=
\frac{16m^3}{16m^4+4}.$$

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't figure that out.
This helped in proving the sum by induction. But I still am not sure about how to get the sum itself.

I'll upvote your answer once I've enough reputation :)

Comment: You can thank with an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: My proof:]

This is my proof. 
We can represent 
$$\frac{a^3}{a^4+4}$$ as a $$\frac{a-1}{2((a-1)^2+1) } + \frac{a+1}{2((a+1)^2+1) }$$
After that we easily can proof this two summas.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.